# vscode exclude/ silence code analysis for folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some folders with code I just play around with - and often it has errors.

I like to keep it in the same workspace as my project, but is it possible to "silence" the analyser for specific folders?

Like a .gitignore for code analyser.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
watcherExclude inside .vscode/settings.json as below.

```css
{
   "files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/.hg/store/**": true
   }
}
```